# Why my Xampp Apache server cant open one PHP script?

Tags: php, html, apache, xampp

I have been writing one HTML page i will let below this, and a PHP script i will post too. But when i use the HTML page to write information and submit it, i get the "The requested URL was not found on this server." message, i have all files into one folder on htdocs named "html", the html page is named "index" and the script is named "test", thank you so much for your time.

[HTML code]

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">
    <link rel="icon" href="/docs/4.0/assets/img/favicons/favicon.ico">

    <title>Signin Template for Bootstrap</title>

    <link rel="canonical" href="https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/examples/sign-in/">

    <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
    <link href="../../dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Custom styles for this template -->
    <link href="signin.css" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>

  <body class="text-center">
    <form method="post" action="next.php">
      <img class="mb-4" src="https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/assets/brand/bootstrap-solid.svg" alt="" width="72" height="72">
      <h1 class="h3 mb-3" font-weight="normal"> Please sign in </h1>
      <label for="inputEmail" class="sr-only">Email address</label>
      <input type="email" id="inputEmail" class="form-control" placeholder="Email address" required autofocus>
      <label for="inputPassword" class="sr-only">Password</label>
      <input type="password" id="inputPassword" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" required>
      <div class="checkbox mb-3">
        <label>
          <input type="checkbox" value="remember-me"> Remember me
        </label>
      </div>
        <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" type="submit">Sign in</button>
        <p class="mt-5 mb-3 text-muted">&copy; 2017-2018</p>
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

[PHP script](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LMVZS.png)

```
<?php

$handle = fopen("pruebapracticaHE.txt", "a"); 

foreach($_POST as $variable => $value) {

    fwrite($handle, $variable);

    fwrite($handle, "=");

    fwrite($handle, $value);

    fwrite($handle, "\r\n");
}

fwrite($handle, "\r\n");
fclose($handle);

exit
?>
```

Comment: [Never post images of code, data or error messages](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/2310830). Please edit your question and include copy/paste the text into the question, formatted. 
This is so that we can try to reproduce the problem without having to re-type everything, and your question can be properly indexed or read by screen readers.

Answer (score 0):

You said that script name is `test.php`

but what i can see in your HTML code that you set `action="next.php"` in the form instead of `action="test.php"` the right code is :

```
<form method="post" action="test.php">
```

Comment: sorry that was my mistake, the script is named next.php i was very tired haha ty so much

Comment: are you sure your script and html file in the same path ? @AlexUsed